# Bind DNS configuration - IPv6 LAN, netplan

Tags: ubuntu, ipv6, bind, netplan

My ISP has introduced IPv6 to my world and I am happy for that so I don't want to just disable it. However it has introduced some issues.

My issue of the moment is that I want my LAN bind DNS to use a public DNS such as cloudfare's or google's. This is working for IPv4 but for IPv6 the DNS is defaulting to my ISP's.

On the DNS server machine I am setting the nameserver in netplan to my LAN's DNS server IPv4 IP address. The bind configuration forwards to Cloudfare  (1.1.1.1.,1.0.0.1 and 2606:4700:4700::1111, 2606:4700:4700::1001). This passes named-checkconf. I tried adding the cloudfare IPv6 addresses to the netplan config but netplan complains about the ':' characters in the IPv6 addresses.

The output of systemd-resolve --status, shows, along with the correct address for the IPv4 server, two IPv6 addresses which resolve to my ISP's IPv6 DNS servers.

How do I configure my netplan or my LAN DNS to use one of my preferred public DNS servers?

Comment: How did you configure IPv6? Where are the addresses coming from?

Comment: After thinking about your question I made some changes to the configuration and added them to my question. However the situation has not changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For netplan configuration using IPv6 addresses, we enclose the address in quotes. The following adds the Cloudfare public DNS to the nameservers for the device.

```
 nameservers:
    addresses: 10.0.0.110,"2606:4700:4700::1111","2606:4700:4700::1001"]
```

For IPv6 this does not completely override the nameservers provided by the ISP. See this output :

```
  systemd-resolve --status
  Current DNS Server: 2606:4700:4700::1111
     DNS Servers: 10.0.0.110
                  2606:4700:4700::1111
                  2606:4700:4700::1001
                  xxxx:yyyy:z:pppr::q
                  xxxx:yyyy:z:pppp::q
```

The LAN DNS will resolve LAN hostnames and then next in line come the Cloudfare IPv6 DNS and then finally the ISP's IPV6 DNS.